# hide hgroup on condition

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i have my hGroups as like

```
<s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="baseline" id="Scale">
        <s:Label width="80" text="Scale:" fontWeight="bold" textAlign="right"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="scaleDropdown" minWidth="155" change="handleScaleDropdownChange(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup> 

    <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="baseline" id="Precision">
        <s:Label width="80" text="Precision:" fontWeight="bold" textAlign="right"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="precisionDropdown" minWidth="155" change="handlePrecisionDropdownChange(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="baseline" id="Units">
        <s:Label width="80" text="Units:" fontWeight="bold" textAlign="right"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="unitDropdown" minWidth="155" change="handleUnitDropdownChange(event)"/>
    </s:HGroup>
```

and i m trying to hide the hgroups on a condition when this bean  tagInfoData have a value "notworking" otherwise it will shown..
should i need to write code in the creation complete as all this is in a pop up window of the button click event

i m using this

```
if(tagInfoData.selectionType.match("notworking"))
            {
                Scale.visible=true;
                Precision.visible=true;
                Units.visible=true;
            }
            else
            {
                Scale.visible=false;
                Precision.visible=false;
                Units.visible=true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In each of the HGroups you want to hide, add `visible="{myFunc(tagInfoData)}"`

Then define:

```
internal function myFunc(tagInfoData:whateverTypeItIs):Boolean{
  return ! tagInfoData.selectionType.match("notworking")
}
```

Make sure `tagInfoData` is defined as `[Bindable]`

Comment: it works on the selection of the dropdown bbut i want to check it on the popup load.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please explain a bit further